# ASP.NET Core disable HTTPS

Tags: c#, linux, docker, asp.net-core, https

I have a dockerized ASP.NET Core app that I'm trying to run locally under Linux (Fedora 33). I'd like to disable HTTPS so I don't have to deal with constant certificate errors.

To do this I simply disabled the HTTPS redirect feature which is included by default, however the app then wasn't responding to any HTTP requests at all.

I managed to get the dev version of the app to run on HTTP by explicitly configuring Kestrel in Startup.cs:

```
webBuilder.UseKestrel(options => {
    options.ListenAnyIP(5000);
});
```

However, it isn't working for the Production version of the app. Whenever I send a request to http://0.0.0.0:5000, I just get a `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer` error.

Running `netstat -ap` in the container doesn't show the app as being bound to the port:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 localhost:46825         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 localhost:36022         0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27739639 1/dotnet             /tmp/dotnet-diagnostic-1-3889474-socket
```

During startup the app also doesn't display the same information that I would normally expect, e.g. the following from another of my dockerized ASP.NET Core apps that *does* use HTTPS:

```
web-prod_1  | Hosting environment: Production
web-prod_1  | Content root path: /app
web-prod_1  | Now listening on: https://[::]:443
web-prod_1  | Now listening on: http://[::]:80
web-prod_1  | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

The app doesn't print any of this on start, which is a little concerning.

I'd really appreciate any help with this, I've tried just about everything I can think of and I'm pulling my hair out over it.

**EDIT**
The cause of this was unrelated to HTTPS - a HostedService with a StartAsync that didn't terminate was being added in Startup.cs. Somehow this was stopping the rest of the app from starting, but only in production builds. Moving the `AddHostedService` call to Program.cs resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But is the container engine actually starting with the flags to bind the container and hosts ports? Conection reset means that the port is closed and actively rejecting connection.

You mention you did a netstat from inside the container, can you run another one from the host while the container is running? I like to use `netstat -plnt`

If your container is exposing the correct ports to the OS you should see it and be able to reach it at localhost:port, here I have a mysql proxy exposing 3306

```
❯ sudo netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

     1/init
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      300988/containers-r
```

Which I had to specify the port binding when launching it (depending on your container engine this is done in different flags/options)

```
docker run -ti -p 3306:3306 eu.gcr.io/xxx-xx/svc-xx-xx-tests
```

Comment: I'm using docker-compose to handle the docker options, including the port binding. The port is showing up as expected on the host side under the program name `docker-proxy`. I'm also running a postgres container alongside it, and I can access postgres just fine from the host.

Comment: Just figured out the cause of this - I was adding a HostedService in Startup.cs which has a StartAsync that doesn't terminate, which was stopping the rest of the app from starting. Adding the HostedService in Program.cs instead resolved the issue.

Comment: Awesome! I guess it would be useful if you edited the original post with the resolution, in case anybody ends up here looking for answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

1st cheek by other browser
or
cheek blocking antivirus or firewall of your PC may interrupted  it.
then
change the port number before by cheeking the ip and port number by ip scanner.

as you now when you need change http to https need SSL certificate , so set disable option  Tools->option->environment->webbrowsers

Comment: I don't think this is applicable on the dev environment OP is using to be honest. Will to help is appreciated but I don't think this is really applicable to containers running inside a native linux host. Where do these menus you mention come from?